# How to upload CSV file on Mac using Selenium Java having no input tag

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, file-upload, ui-automation

While clicking on upload button desktop application opening to select a csv file.
Send Keys not working as no input type as file . Robot class also not working.

[image]

[image]

I tried send keys as well as robot class , nothing is working . Can someone help here pls.

I used below robot class

StringSelection stringSelection= new StringSelection(file.getAbsolutePath());

```
   //Copy to clipboard 
   
 Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard().setContents(stringSelection, null);
 browserDriver.waitTime(MainConfig.timeout_for_AJAX);
       Robot robot = new Robot();

                // Cmd + Tab is needed since it launches a Java app and the browser looses focus

                robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_META);

                robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
                robot.delay(1000);
                robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_META);

                robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);

                robot.delay(1000);

                //Open Goto window

                robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_META);

                robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);

                robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_G);

                robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_META);

                robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);

                robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_G);

                //Paste the clipboard value

                robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_META);

                robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_V);

                robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_META);

                robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_V);

                //Press Enter key to close the Goto window and Upload window

                robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);

                robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);

                robot.delay(1000);

                robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);

                robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
```

Comment: Please post the HTML snippet as code in your question (see [Why I should not upload images of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557)). Also, you say it's a desktop app, yet you are posting HTML which suggests it's a web app. Which is it?